# No Map Received in Rviz while trying out gmapping

Tags: navigation, gmapping, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! Newbie here. I was trying to run gmapping on our own model but I can't seem to solve this problem in rviz, it says no map received. My global fixed frame is odom and map is subscribed to /map topic. I am trying to generate a map. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and ROS noetic for this. My tf frames are

**world->base_footprint->based_stabelized->base_link->laser**

**map->odom**

Can someone help me with this one? Is there any way I can modify the tf frames?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397768/no-map-received-in-rviz-while-trying-out-gmapping./) by [mgrallos](https://answers.ros.org/users/91433/mgrallos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2022-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
Your tf should be **map->odom->base_footprint->...**.
Also, your global fixed frame will be **map**.

---

Originally posted by [charithreddy101](https://answers.ros.org/users/99985/charithreddy101/) with karma: 11 on 2022-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgrallos](https://answers.ros.org/users/91433/mgrallos/) on 2022-03-21**:
Hi I figure that I need to change the tf tree as well. How do I exactly do that?

**Comment by [charithreddy101](https://answers.ros.org/users/99985/charithreddy101/) on 2022-03-22**:
Please give more information regarding your problem while asking the question so that people can give you an exact solution. Include if you are working on a simulated model by using any gazebo plugins, controllers or making a real robot.

Coming to the tf, if you are using the gazebo plugins or calculation odom data using math, you must have declared your odom frame and base_footprint in the plugin itself. It will directly create a transform between /odom and /base_footprint

Else, you can also create a static transform as @nigeno said.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, you need to make sure that you have /map published.

To check it, run:

```
rostopic list
```

see that you have /map in the list.

To check /map message published, run:

```
rostopic echo /map
```

Next, if you have the /map published but you don't see it in Rviz, then you should have a problem in Rviz setup. If you found that /map is not published, check your gmapping, it might be that you don't have proper /tf or other reasons.

---

Originally posted by [nigeno](https://answers.ros.org/users/91893/nigeno/) with karma: 76 on 2022-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgrallos](https://answers.ros.org/users/91433/mgrallos/) on 2022-03-21**:
Hi, thanks. I have map in my rostopic list. According to my research, I need to modify TF tree but I really have no idea how to do. I only knew how to set odom_fram and base_frame and it create a separate TF tree

**Comment by [nigeno](https://answers.ros.org/users/91893/nigeno/) on 2022-03-21**:
it's not clear why you would need the transforms if you have /map topic. But anyways..

What's your relation between base_link and odom frames?

The reason why I'm asking is you need to provide two transformations to gmapping to work:
base_link -> laser;
odom -> base_link

If you have them plus /laser topic then gmapping will give you map -> odom transformation plus /map.

The other transforms shouldn't be required for gmapping to work.

To test it out use the following static transforms:

```
rosrun tf2_ros static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 odom base_link

rosrun tf2_ros static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link laser
```

If this works, then you know which transforms you need and you can provide dynamic ones.

**Comment by [mgrallos](https://answers.ros.org/users/91433/mgrallos/) on 2022-05-04**:
Hi thank you for this.